# Finding out my UK National Insurance Number

Tags: usa, united-kingdom, pension, national-id-number

I am turning 65 in April 2023. I worked in the UK until I was 40 I am a UK citizen. I now live in USA. I have forgot my NIN. How do I find this out ad I think I may be entitled to some portion of my pension.

Comment: [This UK Government webpage](https://www.gov.uk/lost-national-insurance-number) lists several methods by which an individual may discover their UK NIN.

Answer (score 1):

This UK Government webpage https://www.gov.uk/lost-national-insurance-number lists the various ways by which you can find out your NINO:

- Sign in to your personal tax account using your Government Gateway user ID and password. (If you don’t already have a user ID, this method is probably not available to you - IIRC setting up the ID requires proof of ID / address that might be complicated for someone who has not lived in the UK for some time)
- find it on an old payslip, P60,
  letters about tax, pensions or benefits
- Ask HMRC for your NINO by filling in form CA5403 and sending it to the address on the form, or contact the National Insurance numbers helpline and answer some questions (you’ll need to fill in form CA5403 if you cannot answer the questions) https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/national-insurance-get-your-national-insurance-number-in-writing-ca5403

You need 10 years of UK National Insurance contributions to be eligible for the new State Pension. The UK has a social security agreement (also known as ‘bilateral agreements’ or ‘reciprocal agreements’) with some countries, including the USA, so if you are eligible to receive a UK State Pension, you will usually get an increase in your pension every year.

If you were born in April 1958 you’ll reach State Pension age in April 2024. You can check your State Pension age here https://www.gov.uk/state-pension-age/y/age

Finally, you might find this summary, from one of the UK’s biggest consumer finance websites, interesting https://www.moneysavingexpert.com/savings/state-pensions/